# XMLAGG duplicates in results

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to implement XMLAGG into a query that I use to find user AccessRights in Teradata. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    A.RoleName
    , B.DatabaseName
    --,  B.AccessRight
    , Trim(Trailing ',' FROM (XmlAgg(Trim(B.AccessRight) || ',' ORDER BY B.AccessRight) (VARCHAR(10000)))) AS AccessRight
FROM DBC.RoleMembers A JOIN DBC.AllRoleRights B
    ON A.RoleName = B.RoleName
    WHERE Grantee='?your_id'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2,1,3
;
```

Previously I would just select the commented line `B.AccessRight` and comb through the results, but I wanted to combine the AccessRights for each role into one row.

The query above does work, but occasionally rows will have duplicates. Here's a quick example of the output:

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| RoleName | DatabaseName | AccessRight |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Role1    | dbA          | CM, CT, CV  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Role2    | dbB          | R, R, R, R  |  <-- Problematic column
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Role3    | dbC          | E, R        |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

I've tried to fix this by adding DISTINCT to my XMLAGG query as I saw in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306144/using-distinct-in-xmlagg-on-duplicating-records) other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326940/db2-distinct-xmlagg-query) here, but I cannot seem to get it right by myself.

Comment: Be aware, that `DBC.AllRoleRights`, restricts name to char(30), use `DBC.AllRoleRightsV` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBC.AllRoleRightsV includes rights on database, table or column level. Thus you may get duplicates on the database level.

```
join ( select distinct databasename, accessright from DBC.AllRoleRightsV ) as B
```

may be of help.

Or add a `where tableName = 'All'` to get only the database-level grants.

Comment: This is really great, thank you! The second suggestion is the one that I went for and that is a frustratingly simple solution haha