# Teradata Query To Solve Below Scenario

Tags: teradata

I have below scenario and want to write query to get the output.
Can you please help me with this.

***Input :***

```
Column1 Column2
X       1
X       2
X       3
Y       1
Y       2
```

***Expected Output :***

```
Column1 Column2
X       1,2,3
Y       1,2
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50392503/2527905 shows a solution using `xmlagg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
SELECT Column1,TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(Column2||',' ORDER BY Column2 ) (VARCHAR(100)))) Column2  FROM database.table
GROUP BY 1
```